# How to get paragraph field values?

Tags: entities, paragraphs

I'd like to create a product list in drupal and send it in a webservice.
For this I created an entity type with paragraphs for each product.
How can I load the paragraph and access its fields? Until now I see only the target_id and target_revision_id of the product. Thanks!

```
$nodestorage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node');
$productslist = $nodestorage->loadUnchanged(9)->toArray();
foreach($productslist['field_products'] as $prod) {
  debug($prod);
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
  [target_id] => 1
  [target_revision_id] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to include the Paragraph entity class, and use `Paragraph::load($entity_id)` to load it.

Example:

```
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph;

$paragraph = Paragraph::load($target_id);
$foo = $paragraph->field_name->value;
```

Comment: The following change worked for me: `$foo = $paragraph->field_name->getValue();`

Answer (score 11):

```
$paragraph = Paragraph::load($target_id);
// Paragraph type could be also useful.
$prgTypeId = $paragraph->getType();
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList $prgMediaField */
$prgMediaField = $paragraph->get('field_media');
$prgMediaFieldValue = $prgMediaField->getValue();
```

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old, but might be helpful for the future.
To load entities referenced by a Node entity you can use the `entity` property. For example, consider the following code:

```
$nodestorage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node');
$node = $nodestorage->loadUnchanged(9);

foreach ($node->field_products as $product) {

  /** @var Entity (i.e. Node, Paragraph, Term) $referenced_product **/
  $referenced_product = $product->entity;

  // Use now the entity to get the values you need.
  $field_value = $referenced_product->field_name->value;
}
```

So no need to load an entity by the entity id, you just simply user `->entity` property over a referenced list of entities.

Comment: Good, but This will get you only one entity per field!

Comment: No, that's not correct, @Dalmaz, that loop will generate every item contained in field_products.

Comment: you're right @Adaddinsane

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to use `referencedEntities()`:

```
$nodestorage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node');
$node = $nodestorage->loadUnchanged(9);
$products_list = $node->{'field_products'}->referencedEntities();
```